# Can we instantiate an abstract class? Is it possible?

Tags: java, abstract

I read in SCJP6 that an abstract class cannot be instantiated. But read somewhere that they can be instantiated. Is is true? I am new to Java and would like if anyone could explain this in detail. An example would also be a good.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125552/does-the-jvm-internally-instantiate-an-object-for-an-abstract-class/30125593#30125593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reference of an abstract class, but cant instantiate it. For eg.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public abstract void abstractMethod();
    public  void concreteMethod(){
        System.out.println("am in concreteMethod");
    }

}

public class ExtndClass extends AbstractClass{

    @Override
    public void abstractMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(" am in extended class");
    }
    public static void main(String...arg){
        AbstractClass abs = new ExtndClass();
        abs.abstractMethod();
        abs.concreteMethod();

    }

}
```

Output:

```
am in extended class
am in concreteMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.
>
> Abstract classes are similar to interfaces. You cannot instantiate them...